# Empty nested array when initializing state object

Tags: reactjs

I've the following state initialised in a react app:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        meetings: [],
  }
}
```

I need `this.state.meetings` to contain `{ Meetings: [] }` until it is populated based on user action. How can i set this before the page renders?

The reason is that i have map functions running on `this.state.meetings.Meetings` and so i get an undefined error, which makes sense if the default is []. Rather than handle this in the code i wonder if i can just set `Meetings: []` as a default value?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just set `this.state = { meetings: { Meetings: [] } }`?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly discourage you to store it as a nested structure. Keep it as flat as possible. So instead of directly setting the nested field `Meetings` inside state, just push or replace the data received from the api in the `meetings` field.

```
yourApiCall.then((response) => {      // some pseudo code
   this.setState({ meetings: response.Meetings }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's relatively simple, simply do

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        meetings: {
            Meetings: []
        },
  }
}
```

p.s. it also isn't good practice to have your object parent name be the same as a child :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do `this.state = { meetings: { Meetings: [] } }` because javascript is type free, this.state.mettings can assign to a [] later on.

Or a safer way:

```
// if meetings.Meetings is undefined, use empty array
const Meetings = this.state.meetings.Meetings || [].
//use Meetings to do stuff
```